# Duplicate checking of javascript object list with in a certain property

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have javascript object list and object like this

```
var student = function (config) 
               { 
                config = config || {}
                this.id = config.id || 1;
                this.Name = config.Name || "Shohel";
                this.Roll = config.Roll || "04115407";
                this.Session = config.Session || "03-04";
                this.Subject = config.Subject || "CSE";
               };
var students = [];
students.push(new student({ id: 2 }));
students.push(new student({ id: 3, Name: "Rana" }));
students.push(new student({ id: 4, Name: "Shipon" }));
students.push(new student({ id: 5, Name: "Pira" }));
```

Now I want to push another object like this

```
students.push(new student({ id: 3, Name: "Rana" }));
```

It is working without any exceptions but I want to check whether this object whose

> id is: 3 and Name:"Rana"

already exists in the students list and whether I have too many lists like customers, products, sales etc. then duplicate checking is not possible for every list for me. It will be a hassle for me.

How can I make a generic method for any type of list in javascript that can check for duplicates ?

Comment: BTW, you are not using the function as a prototypical constructor, so you should remove the `new` there.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala, Thanks. Can you give me full code specifications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of the possible ways. May be its not the most efficient one, but it does the job pretty well.

```
Array.prototype.pushUnique = function (item) {
    var newObj = JSON.stringify(item);
    if (~(this.map(function (obj) { return JSON.stringify(obj); }).indexOf(newObj))) {
        return false;
    } else {
        this.push(item);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Use `pushUnique` method to push values to the array, and catch for the exceptions like this

```
students.pushUnique(new student({id : 2}));
students.pushUnique(new student({id : 3, Name : "Rana"}));
students.pushUnique(new student({id : 2})); // This will throw an error
```

**Note:**

This will not work when you use plain JSON object like following

```
students.pushUnique({id : 2, Name: "Rana"});
students.pushUnique({Name: "Rana", id : 2});
```

Since the object key sequence is changed and it will result in a different sting when stringified

**Edit: (for case mentioned in comments)**

If you want to check uniquness for specific keys then you can modify the function like this.

```
Array.prototype.pushUnique = function (item, uniqueKeys) {
    var newObj = {}, i , keyLen, arr, key;

    if (!uniqueKeys) { uniqueKeys = Object.keys(item); } else if (!(uniqueKeys instanceof Array)) {
        uniqueKeys = [uniqueKeys];
    }

    keyLen = uniqueKeys.length;
    i = keyLen;
    while (i--) { key = uniqueKeys[i]; newObj[key] = item[key]; }
    newObj = JSON.stringify(newObj);

    arr = this.map(function (obj) {
        var obj_temp = {};
        i = keyLen;
        while (i--) { key = uniqueKeys[i]; obj_temp[key] = obj[key]; }
        return JSON.stringify(obj_temp);
    });

    if (~arr.indexOf(newObj)) {
        return false;
    } else {
        this.push(item);
        return true;
    }
}
```

and use it like

```
students.pushUnique({Name: "Rana", id : 2}, ["id"]); // Pass keys in an array as second parameter
```

Comment: You are great. can you give me suggestion how can i return true or false without using throw new Error('Duplicate object');

Comment: hi @Салман, i have same question, can you use indexOf() ?. and how can i catch that have failed?

Comment: You mean using indexOf directly on the array? it will check for equality I guess, which will always be false since no two objects will be considered equal. @naota Since he is using a function as object, it will preserve the key sequence for all the objects unlike the case I shown above in note.

Comment: Hi @Салман, If you push `{id : 2, Name: "Rana"}` into array and stringfy it, the string could be `{Name: "Rana", id : 2}`. Because JSON.stringfy doesn't guarantee the order. The document is here (Description): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

Comment: @naota Yes, I am aware, that's what I mentioned above in Note. In this case he is using a function to create objects, the keys will always be in order in which they are defined in the constructor.

Comment: @Салман, Thanks. I understand what you say. Sorry but I'm not sure it's so. What do you think of this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order

Comment: @Салман, Thanks. I want to check duplicate for only property wise, whether it can be id, Name, or Name, Session or Session, Subject. no need to check other property except my providing property. How can i make support to your method?is there any alternative way?

Comment: @Md.ShohelRana Checkout the updated code. It should work for specific keys.

Comment: @Салман, I am facing another problem, i want to check this entry students.pushUnique(new student({ id: 5, Name: "Rana" }), ["id,Name"]), here if 'id' and 'Name' is same then duplicate, other wise not duplicate, but your method check whether id or name exist, this will be '&&' operation not '||' operation.

Comment: It is `&&` operation only, you haven't passed the parameters correctly. It should be `["id", "Name"]` instead of `["id,Name"]`

Answer (score 0):

You should go to a `Factory` concept. Try something like this:

```
var _cache = {};
function recicleObject(type, options){
    // Check if type already registered
    if(!_cache[type])
        _cache[type] = [];

    // Check if ID is already taken
    if(_cache[type][options.id]){
        // Return the already made object
        return _cache[type][options.id];
    }else{
        var obj = new window[type](options);
        _cache[type][options.id] = obj;
        return obj;
    }
}
```

And then use it like this:

`var newStudent = recicleObject('student', {id: ....});`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But i want to make common validate method that can check for duplicates. i don't know what are the properties will be check. so you can not fixed options.id...... i can provide checking property as string when will call.

Answer (score 0):

An alternate solution would be to keep another array for the student ids.
Before pushing each element check if the student id array has that id, proceed if there is no entry.

Your modified code would be,

```
var students = [];
var studentIds= [];

var student = function (config) 
             { 
                config = config || {}
                this.id = config.id || 1;
                this.Name = config.Name || "Shohel";
                this.Roll = config.Roll || "04115407";
                this.Session = config.Session || "03-04";
                this.Subject = config.Subject || "CSE";
               };

var pushStudentObj = function(studentObj){

    if(!studentIds.contains(studentObj.id)){
        students.push(studentObj);
    }

}
```

And to push objects call

```
pushStudentObj(new student({ id: 2 }));
pushStudentObj(new student({ id: 3, Name: "Rana" }));
pushStudentObj(new student({ id: 4, Name: "Shipon" }));
pushStudentObj(new student({ id: 5, Name: "Pira" }));
```

This will effectively push only the objects with new Ids!!